# Hide folder only webpage clicks

Tags: php, .htaccess

Hello I have mobile app and using apis from my web site example

> http://example.com/app/login.php
>   http://example.com/app/logout.php

I want to hide app/ folder for only web site clicks example when user open safari or chrome and write there

> http://example.com/app/login.php
>   http://example.com/app/logout.php

will be show private content our not found, but when my app will do;

> http://example.com/app/login.php
>   http://example.com/app/logout.php

my app will work.

This is possible ?

Comment: This is simply not possible in a reliable manner, since there is no feature in the http protocol that allows for a reliable separation between "apps" and "browsers". http is a protocol, that is all the server can see.

Comment: You _could_ try to interpret the http request headers to _guess_ what type of client _probably_ sent a request. But obviously that is completely unreliable, since headers can shaped by each client to its liking. So one should _not_ do that, it only offers a false sense of security.

Comment: @arkascha thanks dude , if it possible will be perfect !

Comment: May I ask _why_ that is required? Look at it this way: you publish those files / functions inside the `app` "folder". So they are meant for public. So why should it be required to then again "hide" them? That simply makes little sense. Your security model should certainly be robust enough that a file / function you publish can be accessed. Otherwise, what is the sense of publishing something?

Comment: @arkascha in my app nobody see links but if somebody see my folder names in ftp i want dont reach them via browser

Comment: Sorry, but that makes even less sense. A published resource should not be protected by the fact that people don't know a link, it should be protected by security. If it is there, then people can use it. It has to be robust enough so that no damage can be done. Apart from that: you don't want to say that you operate a public ftp server? `ftp`? That protocol from the early 70th that is a security nightmare? If so all other thoughts can certainly simply be ignored :-)

Comment: @arkascha lol nightmaree..

Comment: That was not a joke, it is a simple fact. The old and outdated `ftp` protocol should not be used any more.